# How to run a npm script before executing the build command when deploying my GatsbyJS static site on Netlify?

Tags: node.js, git, netlify

I have a npm script called `clone-or-pull` that I want to run (via `npm run clone-or-pull`) before Netlify runs the build command to deploy my static site built using GatsbyJS?

BTW - since my static site is built using GatsbyJS, the build command Netlify would run by default is `gatsby build`. **However, I would like Netlify to execute `npm run clone-or-pull` before executing `gatbsy build`.**

So how can I run a npm script before executing the build command when deploying my GatsbyJS static site on Netlify?

---

FYI - i want to execute `npm run clone-or-pull` to clone my reusable assets repo, which contains the necessary sass/image/font resources I need for my gatbsyjs static site.

Comment: I think I need to use git subtrees to create a copy of my private repo before sending the deploy. I was trying to avoid subtrees/submodules, but I think this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to run a custom npm script before executing the build command (`gatbsy build` in my case) when deploying a site on Netlify. But before I show my solution, here is a snippet of my `package.json`:

GatsbyJS already created a npm script called `build` that runs `gatsby build` command:

**package.json:**

```
  "build": "gatsby build",
  "clone-or-pull": "node clone-or-pull-assets.js"
```

So here is my solution:

1. create `prebuild` npm script that executes `clone-or-pull` npm script
2. create `netlify.toml` file that specifies to run `npm run build` instead of `gatsy build` (since `npm run build` will run the `prebuild` script and then run `gatsby build`

**1. create `prebuild` npm script in package.json**:

```
  "prebuild": "npm run clone-or-pull",
  "build": "gatsby build",
  "clone-or-pull": "node clone-or-pull-assets.js"
```

**2. create `netlify.toml` to run `build` script:**

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
```